# Error executing process Utility 'mysqldump' not found in client home '/home/andy/snap/dbeaver-ce/212/.local/share/DBeaverData/drivers

Tags: dbeaver

Anyone having issues dumping a database using DBeaver?...

[image]

You'd assume

```
Utility 'mysqldump' not found in client home
```

**could** be found in a database application? On my local machine:

[image]

so, `mysqldump` is installed?

Comment: I'm using DataGrip from here on in. It just works.

Answer (score 0):

> so, mysqldump is installed?

Yes, it's installed.
You need correctly specify path to binary of mysqldump utility.

[Dbeaver export wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fx7l8.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).